# Determine code size of a file

Tags: atmega, code-size

I have program and compile it to Hex file which is available [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/9bo3uyxtzkm8s58/main.hex). I burned this Hex file into the ATMega card 163 and it runs correctly. Now I want to know the code size of the file.

Running `size main.hex` gives:

```
text: 0
data: 7072
bss:0
dec:7072
hex: 1ba0
filename: main.hex
```

Why are the text size and bss 0? What is the meaning of data size?

Answer (score 0):

I think *text* should be executable code. *Data* is initialized stuff going to RAM and *bss* non initialized RAM content (which can be 0). No idea why all you code goes to *data* but I suppose it's problem of makefile or building scripts.